# Is there a reason I can't mount with a prefixpath in this scenario?

Tags: mount, samba

I'm not sure why this scenario is so weird, but I have a particular combination where this command won't work:

```
mount -o username=guest //192.168.1.70/Volume_1/Movies/Library /storage/movies
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: mounting //192.168.1.70/Volume_1/Movies/Library on /storage/movies failed: No such file or directory
```

Yet when I go:

```
mount -o username=guest //192.168.1.70/Volume_1 /storage/movies
```

It works and I can navigate to /storage/movies/Movies/Library and see the contents. This is not what I want, as I want to enter from the desired mount point.

**My particular scenario.**

I am trying to mount a share from a DNS-323 NAS device onto a raspberry pi running openelec.

**What does work?**

I can mount shares with prefixpaths from windows devices and linux devices onto the openelec raspi without any problems.

I can also mount the directory in question from the NAS onto other devices both Windows and Linux.

Why is this particular combination giving me problems? Is there another parameter I can provide to make it work? Is it possibly a permissions issue?